# Simple raw socket server in C/C++ on Linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, sockets, raw-sockets

I am trying to build an Ethernet network with raw sockets. I cannot use TCP/IP, UDP, or any other protocol.

This is because it will be communicating with very simple hardware that won't have the resources to handle all the different protocol layers. 
My network will consist of 1 host computer communicating with several pieces of hardware through an Ethernet switch. At this point I basically just want to send simple packets to each piece of hardware and to establish a simple server I can expand on. My system is running Linux and the server needs to be written in C or C++.

I have been trying to find information on how to use raw sockets, but everyone always says not to use them and provides no information. I have a pretty strong programming background but no networking experience. 
Can anyone provide any information on how to get started or where a relevant tutorial can be found?

Comment: Network sockets are virtually synonymous with the IP protocol. Even if you abandon the IP protocol, you're just going to have to implement your own that is similar. Check your assumptions.

Comment: I have to agree with Stargazer712, the overhead needed to implement the other layers is really not that much. If you use udp most of the fields can be constant.

Comment: [More research](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UIP_(micro_IP)) is recommended before making resource statements.

Comment: So, since everyone always suggests avoiding raw sockets, perhaps someone could fill in some details for me. To use protocols like IP or tcp/udp, does there need to be any infrastructure at all on the client side? To be clear, my clients are pure hardware. The host computer has full access to any socket protocols, but the clients it is communicating with through the Ethernet switch do not have any software capabilities. Can someone explain why IP or tcp/udp are more desirable for this?

Comment: Hi, did you finally make the Raw socket without tcp/udp ?

Comment: @user3217310 So it turned out I needed to send raw _packets_, not use raw sockets. This resource was the most helpful: [sending-raw-ethernet-packets-from-a-specific-interface-in-c-on-linux](http://austinmarton.wordpress.com/2011/09/14/sending-raw-ethernet-packets-from-a-specific-interface-in-c-on-linux/)

Answer (score 7):

There are various tutorials on the net which are relatively easy to find.  A good place for you to start would be with one such tutorial: [Sockets Tutorial](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/C_C++/socket.htm).  It includes a simple client/server example in C (though the example is using the TCP protocol).

More results:

[Raw Sockets programming on Linux with C](http://www.binarytides.com/raw-sockets-c-code-on-linux/)

[LINUX SOCKET PART 17 Advanced TCP/IP - THE RAW SOCKET PROGRAM EXAMPLES](http://www.tenouk.com/Module43a.html)

[Here is a comprehensive list of google search results on raw socket programming in C](https://www.google.com/search?q=raw+sockets+linus&sugexp=chrome,mod=9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&biw=1782&bih=779&sclient=psy-ab&q=raw+sockets+Linux+C&oq=raw+sockets+Linux+C&gs_l=serp.3..0i30j0i8i30.4339.8147.0.8362.12.12.0.0.0.0.101.1096.10j2.12.0.les%3Bcqn%2Crate_low%3D0-035%2Crate_high%3D0-035%2Cmin_length%3D2%2Ccconf%3D1-2%2Csecond_pass%3Dfalse%2Cnum_suggestions%3D1%2Cignore_bad_origquery%3Dtrue..0.0...1c.1.9qREijsQxCc&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=9ab7bdb26321ca5d)

Comment: He wants raw sockets, not tcp/udp.

Comment: @CrazyCasta, he probably does, he just doesn't know it yet.

Comment: @Stargazer712 While I agree it's foolish to use raw sockets, especially with no background in networking, he was pretty explicit in what he wants. This would be more appropriate in a comment suggesting he abandon this idea of raw sockets.

Comment: Thank you for the raw sockets links. The Google search results aren't particularly helpful, since I've been reading webpages found on Google for weeks, and 95% of those are irrelevant or provide no useful information.  But the first 2 are providing some helpful insight.